# Join query for Postgres 9.4 JSONB field using Peewee ORM

Tags: peewee, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

Am using peewee in one of my projects and being from a Django background, i like it great.

Am planning to use the newly introduced JSONB in postgres 9.4 extensively. However, I have no clue to how can I perform a join operation using JSONB keys.

I assume an example would be excellent for the whole community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
User.select().join(Metadata, on=Metadata.data['user_id'] == User.id)
```

Where `Metadata.data` is a JSON field.

Comment: Great. As simple as it can get. Thanks. :)